# Java : Duplication of methods

Tags: java, class, oop

This feels like such a basic question but this is all new for me:

I have a Person and Room class, both of which have a list of Item objects.

```
public class Person{
  private ArrayList<Item> items;

  public Person() {
    items = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addItem(){
  ...
  }

  public void removeItem(){
  ...
  }

}    

public class Room {

  private ArrayList<Item> items;

  public Room () {
    items = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addItem(){
  ...
  }

  public void removeItem(){
  ...
  }

}
```

The item methods e.g. addItem() are duplicated in both the Room class and the Person class which wasn't very nice. I thought about making a separate Inventory class which has a list of items and item methods and then every room and person would have an inventory.

But then I wouldn't be able to call the Item methods from a Person or Room if I use a private Inventory field.

What's the best way to stop duplication here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could create appropriate methods in the Person and Room classes which delegate to the inventory object.

Comment: Your solution seems the right way. I would say you try to implement the aggregate design pattern. Maybe the thougts help a little bit: http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Use_the_Aggregate_Design_Pattern_to_Reduce_Coupling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right.  Making a separate inventory class would be a good OOP design.

I'm glad you didn't say making a parent class to `Room` and `Person` since while that would save you the duplication, Rooms and Person's aren't related so they shouldn't really be related in an Object Oriented sense either.

You can use delegation to delegate the add/remove items to your `Inventory` field.

```
public class Room {

    private Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        inventory.addItem(item);
    }

    public void removeItem(Item item) {
        inventory.removeItem(item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Some people are proposing exposing the Inventory and then having a public add/remove methods on that `person.getInventory().addItem(item)`. I think that would violate the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: +1. Regarding your “edit”: I think it depends on the actual domain whether this is a violation or not.  “Give me your inventory and let me add / remove items to / from it” might be a semantically correct operation in some domains while in others, it won't.  For starters, a good test might be to ask: Does a `Person` *have* an `Inventory` or does it just happen to *use* one internally?

Comment: Thanks! I thought of doing this but was wondering if there were other ways. But now I think your way is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think the inventory class is the best way to go here. You would be able to use the item methods by creating a getter for the inventory inside `Person`and `Room`.

Comment: That didn't seem like a nice solution to me. Is it a good idea to use a getter in this way?

Comment: You could use delegate methods as others suggested, but I don't see the problem with using a getter for the inventory. The inventory class will have a private `ArrayList` and public methods for adding and removing items.

Comment: By not using a getter and delegating to the Person or Room class you have better encapsulation as you are not revealing the detail of how items are stored to the caller.

Comment: What details are hidden by delegating to the `Person` and `Room` classes that can not be hidden in the inventory class?

Comment: The fact that a Person or Room uses an Inventory to store items. The caller shouldn't care how items are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your business domain is, you could have an abstract storage container class too that they both inherit from. The abstract storage container would have the methods on it, so you could still call them directly.

You also could give both classes an empty interface of IStorageContainer and then create a new static class with a static method that took in the first parameter of IStorageContainer.

Then you could call AddItem(thisPerson, item) and RemoveItem(thisPerson, item) but be able to reuse those two methods for both classes, using the same code and implementation.